# Codeigniter Validation Error While Using 0 value in an input

Tags: forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I think there is a bug in codeigniter form validation class.

My code is working perfectly fine if value is greater than zero but if it's "0" set_value function is not working:

Controller:

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required|is_natural');
```

View:

```
<?  if(set_value('age')) { ?>           
<input id="age" name="age" type="text" value="<?=set_value('age')?>" />                                          
<? } else { ?>
<input id="age" name="age" type="text" value="Age" /> 
<? } ?>
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form field is not being repopulated when the value is `0` because your `if` statement evaluates it to `FALSE` and then outputs the form field without the `value` attribute.

So, get rid of the `if` statement. You simply want this instead:

```
<input id="age" name="age" type="text" value="<?=set_value('age')?>" />
```

`set_value()` will either return the value (if one is provided), and either the default value or an empty string if no value is provided.